# BigQuery - How can i make Merge Statement Handle Duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a table which uses compound columns to uniquely identify each row of data.. So they are times we get duplicate rows. I have an Merge Statement that copies data from the source table to the destination. Anytime we have duplicate rows on the Source Table. The Merge statement copies the Duplicate along with the other rows of data to the Destination. The merge statement is

```
        MERGE `project.dataset.destination` T
        USING `project.dataset.source` S
        ON  (T.department = S.department OR T.department IS NULL and S.department IS NULL) AND
            (T.category = S.category OR T.category IS NULL AND S.category IS NULL) AND
            (T.subcategory = S.subcategory OR T.subcategory IS NULL AND S.subcategory IS NULL) AND
            (T.subset = S.subset OR T.subset IS NULL AND S.subset IS NULL) AND
            (T.country = S.country OR T.country IS NULL AND S.country IS NULL) AND
            (T.state = S.state OR T.state IS NULL AND S.state IS NULL) AND
            (T.county = S.county OR T.county IS NULL AND S.country IS NULL) AND
            (T.date = S.date OR T.date IS NULL AND S.date IS NULL)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ((department = "SPORT" AND subcategory IN ("FOOTBALL", "PONG")) AND 
                     (country IN("USA", "CANADA") )) THEN 
            INSERT ROW
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
            DELETE
```

My question is; is there any way i can handle the Inserting of Duplicates to the Destination Table?
Or if the Duplicates rows is Inserting into the Destination. when this Merge statement runs the next day; is there anyway i can modify this Merge Statement to Delete any duplicate found on the Destination table?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is duplicate ? I mean  what does define duplicate in your scenratio?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the row in the table with the new value?

Comment: @eshirvana duplicate is having the same row of data appear more than one on the source table... not being unique

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am trying to insert the data in the source into the destination.. but i dont want the duplicate data

Comment: Why don't you schedule an additional BQ-SQL to handle duplicate records as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

General guideline for a good SQL question: provide sample source table and dest table, then the expected results.

That said, based on the comments, 'duplicate' here means:

> having the same row of data appear more than one on the source table

Deduping the source table could happen in a subquery like

```sql
        MERGE `project.dataset.destination` T
        USING (
          SELECT ... 
          FROM `project.dataset.source` 
          GROUP BY <your_unique_key>
          ) S
        ON ...
```